# How to determine probe order within an init call level in linux

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Linux does provides us with 7 different init levels to choose from based on our need. I was wondering within an init level How does it determine which module's init to be called. For example Driver A and Driver B both have module init defined @ fs_initcall level. How does Linux determine which one to call first.

Comment: It’s determined by link order.

Answer (score 3):

For same level, it is determined by the Makefile order, for example, in my drivers/input/touchscreen/Makefile:

```
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_IT7259_I2C)    += it7259_ts_i2c.o
obj-$(CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_FTS)           += focaltech_touch/
```

it7259 will in be called first.

You can find the detail order in out/system.map:

```
c116ae80 T __initcall6_start
...
c116b278 t __initcall_it7259_ts_driver_init6
c116b27c t __initcall_fts_ts_init6
...
c116b6a4 T __initcall7_start
```

If you change the order in Makefile, make sure to clean "out" folder, and rebuild, then system.map will be updated with new order.

More info:

1. Below definition will be used to make .init.data section:

   ## define module_init(x)    __initcall(x);

   ## define __define_initcall(level,fn,id) \

   static initcall_t **initcall_##fn##id __used \
       __attribute**((**section**(".initcall" level ".init"))) = fn

each __initcall(x) will become an item in .init.data section, like:

```
c116b27c t __initcall_fts_ts_init6
```

2. initcall flow when boot up:
   start_kernel-->rest_init-->kernel_init-->do_basic_setup-->do_initcalls

   static void __init do_initcalls(void)
   {
       int level;

   ```
   for (level = 0; level < ARRAY_SIZE(initcall_levels) - 1; level++)
   do_initcall_level(level);
   ```

   }

   static void __init do_initcall_level(int level)
   {
       extern const struct kernel_param __start___param[], __stop___param[];
       initcall_t *fn;

   ```
   strcpy(static_command_line, saved_command_line);
   parse_args(initcall_level_names[level],
           static_command_line, __start___param,
           __stop___param - __start___param,
           level, level,
           repair_env_string);

   for (fn = initcall_levels[level]; fn < initcall_levels[level+1]; fn++)
   do_one_initcall(*fn);
   ```

   }

   static initcall_t *initcall_levels[] __initdata = {
       __initcall0_start,
       __initcall1_start,
       __initcall2_start,
       __initcall3_start,
       __initcall4_start,
       __initcall5_start,
       __initcall6_start,
       __initcall7_start,
       __initcall_end,
   };

And in vmlinux.lds, it will go to address in .init.data section.