# What is the difference between `module_param_cb()` and `device_param_cb()`?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

Can someone explain the differences between `module_param_cb()` and `device_param_cb()` in `linux/moduleparam.h`—specifically about the use cases for these two functions? I was unable to find any documentation on `device_param_cb()`.

Comment: It's explained in the mentioned header file: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7-rc3/source/include/linux/moduleparam.h#L167 and https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7-rc3/source/include/linux/moduleparam.h#L250. TL;DR: there are a system of so called _initcall__:s (initialization calls, see the last parameter to the `__level_param_cb()`). These are just placed on different linker sections.

Comment: The kernel_param struct itself for module_param_cb and device_param_cb should be placed in the same section "__param". The difference between them is the "level" value (aka initcall level), -1 for module_param_cb and 6 for devcie_param_cb, to make sure the parameters evaluated before loading (module or intree). Difference level means the phase during kernel loading (early or late): 1:core/2:postcore/3:arch/4:subsys/5:fs/6:device/7:late. More info at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55839142/how-to-determine-probe-order-within-an-init-call-level-in-linux